# How to filter an expression by columns in different tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new in DAX and **what i need is create a matrix with different values.**

In my data base i have 4 different tables, the 1st one is about *departments* in a company, the 2nd one is about several *questions* about security they have to ask to their employees (that questions are grouped according the type of risk) and thats the 3rd table, this table is about the *group of questions* and finally the *answers* table where i have the different possible anwers for each group of question such as Yes/No/N.A. for a group of questions or Good/Bad for another group.

I need to get the total number of a specific answer like "No" in a specific group of questions in percentage.

```
Prueba := 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTAX(OPSRespuestas;
                OPSRespuestas[Answer]
               );
        OPSGrupoPreguntas[Grupo]="procedimientos";
        OPSRespuestas[Answer]="no"
             )
```

I tried with this Dax code but it returns the total number for all the groups i have.

I give you the tables which i'm working:

[Questions Table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gpyG.jpg)

[GroupQuestions Table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibNUI.jpg)

[Answers Table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ5BR.jpg)

What i'm getting is this:

[Myresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLtBn.jpg)

However, what i expect to get is that result only for the corresponding group, that is just for *procedimientos*

Comment: I think you should try changing all the semi-colons to commas

Comment: @Deltapimol DAX separator changes dependent on the user regional settings

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a try:

```
Prueba := 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTA(OPSRespuestas[Answer]);
        FILTER(OPSGrupoPreguntas;OPSGrupoPreguntas[Grupo]="procedimientos");
        OPSRespuestas[Answer]="no"
    )
```

Edit: and now?

Comment: This returns me the same as my code. The problem is that when i do this, it give the same total to all my rows in the matrix. What i'm trying to do is that when i execute this code, it give the total only for the value "Procedimientos" and the rest of values that are not equal to "procedimientos" disappear.